# button doesn't add to cart - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm not sure why this is not allowing me to add to the cart.

I have access to the global product but it's not capturing the ID to add to cart

```
<?php
    /**
    * Simple product add to cart
    *
    * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php.
    *
    * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
    * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
    * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
    * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
    * the readme will list any important changes.
    *
    * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
    * @package WooCommerce\Templates
    * @version 3.4.0
    */

    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        return;
    }

    echo wc_get_stock_html( $product ); // WPCS: XSS ok.

    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

        <form 
            class="cart" 
            action="<?php echo esc_url( 
                apply_filters( 
                    'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() 
                ) 
            ); ?>" 
            method="post" 
            enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' );
                woocommerce_quantity_input(
                    array(
                        'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                        'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
                        'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) 
                            ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) 
                            : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
                    )
                );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' );
            ?>      

            <button 
                type="submit" 
                name="add-to-cart" 
                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" 
                class="product_add_to_cart_button uk-button uk-button-primary">
                <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
            </button>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
        </form>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Any JS error in console?

Comment: Stripe.js is loaded more than once.

Comment: Which by the way, it was warning, not an error and I deactivated Woocomerce Stripe to see if it would work and no change

Comment: Is it possible to share the site link.?

Comment: https://www.tonypolicci.com/product/book/

Comment: Please check switching the theme

Comment: didn't work either. Also a new install of woocommerce plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244558/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-lotusms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `Add to cart` button has the following classes: `.add_to_cart_button`, `.product_type_simple`. Also, check if the button has the dataAttr `data-product_id`. These items should be given, otherwise, neither the add-to-cart.js will trigger the ajax call, nor will return a false, which prevents from reloading the page.